# Android Hamburger icon animation Activity switch

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-animation, android-toolbar

How to make a hamburger icon on a toolbar animate to back icon on switching activities?

(This animation in set up and works fine for navigation view, the switch is generally animated by `ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation`)

You can see an example my pressing on any message in Gmail app.

Answer (score 0):

google didn't make that very easy. you will need to create your own implementation of the drawertoggle.Delegate interface, if you want to use the solution with a nav drawer. then you want to extend the DrawerArrowDrawable class in order to control the actual state of the icon. Finally, use a property animator to animate the state change.

in your case, when the new activity is created, you'd want to immediately start animating the icon to its arrow state.

i've written a gist that somewhat illustrates what needs to be done:
https://gist.github.com/urandom/8608fb45fdd489c8cd2bf9654a2139a1

Comment: Thanks, I will try it in a few days.